# No guitar output in headphones

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-studio

I'm trying out Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (from a USB drive).

Headphones are plugged in and working - tested with VLC playing a music file.

Guitar is plugged into an Mbox2 Mini USB audio input. The Mbox is selected as the input device in system settings, and I can see the 'vu meter' move when I strum a chord. BUT, no guitar sound in the headphones!

Can anyone suggest why I can't hear the guitar (in the headphones)?

Comment: What application are you using to do that? You can't expect to automatically monitor your inputs through your headphones, that's not how it works. Try launching something like Audacity and enable monitoring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-) I tried Audacity, Guitarix and Rakarrack, but without success. I suspect it's trying to send the monitor feed to the Mbox2 but I don't have the right headphone jack too test!

Out of interest why can't you monitor your inputs? It would seem to be the logical thing to happen, and certainly that's what happens with 'proper' audio equipment like portastudios.

Comment: You can monitor, you just have to wire it correctly. I guess on PCs hearing your input played back through your output is just not what is commonly expected - keep in mind that for the OS the MBox is just another audio interface. When you say you don't have the right headphone jack, then where do you have your headphones plugged into? You said you were expecting to hear the guitar input in your headphones, but what are they connected to?

Comment: So, I just played around myself a little, and it appears that it is in fact not straightforward to enable monitoring. But you can do it using JACK, which allows you to connect pretty much anything to anything. Start QjackCtl, click "Start", then click "Connect", and in the windows that appears "Expand All". You should see something like "capture" and "playback" ports. Depending on your setup and how many interfaces you have installed, you can connect your capture channels to your playback channels, and you will hear the input in your output.